# Word 2013: Shortcut to insert timestamp into word document

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, date-time, microsoft-word-2013

I'm looking for a very very fast method to insert a timestamp into a Word document. I always know the shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, but doing so inserts a field, that is always automatically updated. And because I need a real timestamp, I consequently have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> to get a fixed date-time string:

To sum up:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
- Mark both fields
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>

And that is not a shortcut, that's expensive overhead! So I'm always faster when I write all by 10-fingers touch-typing.

I search for a real one-hand keyboard shortcut for inserting a fixed date-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record a macro for these actions and assign it to a single keyboard shortcut. This is the exact usecase macros are made for.

Comment: I finally came up to the same solution because I didn't find anything else than a macro based shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found your solution by now but for those of you still looking, Word still has the old date time formats box. In the ribbon its on the Insert tab | Text group. It's the icon that looks like a calendar with a clock in the lower right-hand corner. From the box, you can select your preferred format, make it the default and insert an icon on the QAT. That makes it a 2 click function or you can create a keyboard macro from the 2 click function for faster results.